# Using Javascript, how can I detect a keypress event but NOT when the user is typing in a form field?

Tags: javascript, events, onkeyup, onkeypress

On my Web site, I want to open my search form dynamically when a user hits the question mark key. I can do that using the following code:

```
document.onkeyup = checkKey;
function checkKey(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == '191') { // user inputs the "?" key [shift + /]
        // Do something
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to trigger the action if the user is simply typing a question mark in a comment field or search field. For example, in Gmail you can hit "?" to open keyboard shortcuts overlay, but if you are composing an email and type a "?" the shortcuts don't open.

**How can I detect a keypress event but NOT when the user happens to be typing in a form field?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sniffing on the event `target` property's `tagName` would perhaps be sufficient.  The below obviously isn't exhaustive-- there's several edge cases to consider-- but it's a start.  Try typing when in the form elements and then just when focused elsewhere in the document:

```js
document.onkeyup = checkKey;
function checkKey(evt) {
    const formElements = ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA', 'SELECT', 'OPTION'];
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (formElements.includes(evt.target.tagName)) {
      console.log('ignore me!');
    } else {
      console.log('do something!');
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>my form</h1>
<form>
  <label for="name">name</label>
  <input id="name" name="name" />
  <br/>
  <label for="aboutme">about me</label>
  <textarea id="aboutme" name="aboutme"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <label for="ghostbuster">ghostbuster</label>
  <select id="ghostbuster" name="ghostbuster">
    <option value="winstonzeddmore">Winston Zeddmore</option>
    <option value="egonspangler">Egon Spangler</option>
    <option value="petervenkman">Peter Venkman</option>
    <option value="raystanz">Ray Stanz</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p> some text</p>
```

Comment: You should also include `TEXTAREA`

Comment: @HaoWu - definitely a good call-- I didn't want to build out the whole exhaustive function as I'm not sure the users specific needs.  Including `select` would probably make sense as well, but at that point you might need to get smarter about iterating up parent nodes.  If the OP requires this, I could probably fill out the example to be a more complete approach... on second thought, perhaps I should just do it regardless (the OP is a fellow Chicagoan, after all)

Comment: @Tantalus - also, one edge case I didn't include that you might want to consider-- if the user has a `<button>` element focused.  Depends on what keys you are sniffing on and how you want the form to behave.

Answer (score 0):

In your checkKey function, you have access to the event object.  You can check the target of the event to determine how to handle it.  In this case, you could modify your example to look like this:

```
document.onkeyup = checkKey;
function checkKey(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.target.type === 'input') {
       return;
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == '191') { // user inputs the "?" key [shift + /]
        // Do something
    }
}
```